# Conditional composition operator

Tags: clojure

I'd like to know if there exists some built-in function composition operator in clojure allowing me to rewrite something like:

`(def first-or-identity #(if (sequential? %) (first %) (identity %)))`

into a shorter:

`(def first-or-identity (if-composition sequential? first identity)`

--

The use case would be to be able to write something along those lines:

```
(def eventbus-pub
  (async/pub eventbus (if-composition sequential? first identity)))
```

Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a function:

```
(defn if-composition [tester truer falser]
  (fn [x]
    (if (tester x) (truer x) (falser x))))
```

For example,

```
(map
 (if-composition even? #(quot % 2) #(inc (* 3 %)))
 (range 10))
;(0 4 1 10 2 16 3 22 4 28)
```

It's worth while making the last argument `identity` by default:

```
(defn if-composition
  ([tester truer] (if-composition tester truer identity))
  ([tester truer falser]
   ... ))
```

For example,

```
(map (if-composition odd? #(* 2 %)) (range 10))
;(0 2 2 6 4 10 6 14 8 18)
```

Now we can write your example as

```
(def first-or-identity (if-composition sequential? first))
```

Comment: You can also use `apply` to extend to arbitrary arities: `(fn [& args] if (apply tester args) (apply truer args) (apply falser args))`. Obviously not going to work very well unless the fns all have the same arity, though.

Comment: @user1571406 Yes. I thought that those who didn't see that would be confused by it. And if you put *all* the arguments that *any* of the functions need into the mix, you can always wrap them up as functions that ignore the needless arguments. [Prismatic Graph](https://github.com/prismatic/plumbing) does this associatively.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Brilliant by its simplicity. I especially like the idea of making identity default.